# How to preserve column order while using psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor

Tags: python, psycopg2

```
dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
dict_cur.execute("SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM mytable")
result = dict_cur.fetchall()
print result[0]
>>> {'column2':10, 'column1':12, 'column3':42}
```

How could I preserve column ordering without parsing executed SQL first? It works well with normal cursor when list is returned, but I need access to dictionary keys and therefore need to use RealDictCursor.

**EDIT**: Well, I actually can't. *description* attribute of the cursor object should be used for getting column names.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#namedtuple-cursor) and then use [`namedtuple_obj._asdict()`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) to convert that to an `OrderedDict`.

Note: In ordered to get this functionality "out of the box" we need to have Python version >= 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this "`extras`" package, but normally a cursor should have a property called `description` which is a tuple containing all the columns in order along with some additional information like field type etc.

Try out "`print dict_cur.description`" in a python shell and see what you get.

EDIT: never mind. I did not read your "EDIT"...